# Saving numpy array to GIF using PIL

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to save a series of numpy arrays to a gif using PIL.

When I initialise each frame as a white background (before adding to the frame) for some reason it only saves the first image.

However, when the frame is initialised randomly the whole gif is saved.

Can anyone explain what the problem is in the first instance? Any help appreciated.

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

for i in range(10):
  # Option 1 ---> just saves first frame
  frame = np.full((100,100),255, dtype=np.uint8)
  # Option 2 ---> saves whole gif
  frame = np.random.randint(0, 255, (100, 100), dtype=np.uint8) 

  ##  code to add stuff to frame

  if i == 0:
    frames = np.expand_dims(frame, axis=0)
  else:
    frames = np.concatenate((frames, np.expand_dims(frame, axis=0)), axis=0)

images = [Image.fromarray(frame) for frame in frames]
images[0].save('output.gif', save_all=True, append_images=images[1:], duration=50, loop=0)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This could potentially be related to this issue: https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/2314

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a bug in my code where I was adding to the frame. As a result each of the frames was identical. If PIL detects that the next image is identical then it clearly doesn't append it. Hence why I ended up with just one frame, and why the example above with the same blank image each time also just returns one image. I would be interested to know if there is any way to override this feature, not that it is necessary in this instance.